# Java timer action listener

Tags: java, swing, timer, paintcomponent

could use your help homework involving  swing timers, action listeners and multiple objects. I don't know if posting the question is allowed here but i'm having trouble with the animation, here's what i have so far

> Create a class Particle that has two double fields x and y, a
>   constructor that initializes these fields to random values between 0
>   and 500, methods getX and getY that return their values, and a method
>   void move() that randomly adds or subtracts one to each of the values
>   of x and y. (The quantities added to x and y are two separate random
>   numbers.) Next, create a class ParticleFieldWithTimer that extends
>   JPanel. This class should prefer to be 500 * 500 pixels in size. Its
>   constructor should first fill an ArrayList field with 100
>   Particle objects, then start a Swing Timer that ticks 25 times a
>   second. At each tick, the action listener should first call the method
>   move for each particle, and then call repaint. The paintComponent
>   method of ParticleFieldWithTimer should draw each particle as a 3*3
>   rectangle to its current coordinates. Make sure that the Timer will
>   stop when the user closes the frame

This is the ParticleFieldWithTimer class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class ParticleFieldWithTimer extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Particle> particle = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    Timer timer; 
    boolean b; 
    public ParticleFieldWithTimer (){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));


    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        particle.add(new Particle());
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                // change polygon data
                // ...
                Particle p = new Particle();
                p.move();
                repaint();

            }
        });


    }





}
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (Particle p: particle) {

        double temp1 = p.getX();
        double temp2 = p.getX();
        int tempX = (int) temp1;
        int tempY = (int) temp2;
        g2.fillRect(tempX, tempY, 3, 3);
        }




    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("ParticleField");
        final ParticleFieldWithTimer bb = new ParticleFieldWithTimer();
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(bb);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                try {
                    bb.finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                f.dispose();
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the particle class

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Particle {
private double x , y ;

Random r = new Random();
public Particle () {

    x = r.nextDouble()*500;
    y = r.nextDouble()*500;

}
public Double getX() {
    return x;
}
public Double getY() {
    return y;
}
public void move() {

    x = r.nextInt(2) - 1;
    y = r.nextInt(2) - 1;
    System.out.println(x + "  " + y);
}
```

}

Comment: *"I don't know if posting the question.."*  DYM the specification for the homework?  What is ***your*** question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    particle.add(new Particle());
    timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            // change polygon data
            // ...
            Particle p = new Particle();
            p.move();
            repaint();

        }
    });
}
```

Is the wrong approach, it is create a 100 `Timer`s, which will affect the performance of your system.

You are also creating a new `Particle` each time the timer ticks, which isn't what you really want to do either, you want to affect the `Particle`s you've already created...

Instead, create your particles...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    particle.add(new Particle());
}
```

Then create your `Timer` and within it, iterate through the particles you've already created...

```
timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        for (Particle p : particle) {
            p.move();
        }
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Don't forget to start the timer...

```
timer.start();
```

Or change the color of the `Graphics` context, which is probably still set to the background of the panel...

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.RED);
for (Particle p : particle) {
```

I also noted that...

```
x = r.nextInt(2) - 1;
y = r.nextInt(2) - 1;
```

Isn't doing what you want.  It will always make the values between -1 and 1.  Instead, you want to add the result to the x/y values...

```
x += r.nextInt(2) - 1;
y += r.nextInt(2) - 1;
```

Now, this kind of made the values "drag" across the screen in a (mostly) uniform manner...

You could try using...

```
x += r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : - 1;
y += r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : - 1;
```

But this ended up making them dance around in place (mostly)...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Shouldn't repaint be inside the for loop and what modifications should i make to the paintcomponent?

Comment: No, you want to update the entire model and then do a single `repaint`.  It wouldn't actually make a "lot" of difference, as the `RepaintManager` can consolidate repeated calls to `repaint` into a single paint event, but why take the risk.  Update the model in one step, update the view in the next.  Because `actionPerformed` executes within the context of the EDT, calling `repaint` will have no effect until AFTER the `actionPerformed` method has exited anyway (`paintComponent` can't be called until `actionPerformed` exist)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense. However, there still seems to be something wrong with my program, in the paintcomponent i'm guessing i shouldn't have a for loop but i'm confused as to what i should do

Comment: thank you so much for your help so far, could you also help me with closing the timer when the user closes the window?

Comment: and do you know why the particles are sort of lining up horizontally instead of being truly random in the window?

Comment: To stop the timer you could call `timer.stop()`, but it would simply be easier to use `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, then there is no need for the `WindowListener` either ;) - You should never call `finalize`...it's not for you to play with ;) - Did you see the last few comments about the randimisation of the x/y value?

Comment: The main problem is `r.nextInt(2)` is only ever going to be `0` or `1`, when you use `-1` on it, that makes it `-1` to `0`...